# How to start search from the caret position instead of the beginning of the file in IDE?

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi XE5 but this was in Delphi XE2 too. I don't know what I did but when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, type keyword and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it starts to search from the beginning, not from the current caret pos. Does anyone know a solution to this, please ?

Comment: Check OFF the checkbox **Entire Scope**

Comment: In XE2 there's a little 'chevron' at the right end of the search panel (if it doesn't fit) under the ide editor, click on it.

Comment: Didn't Ctrl+E do forward incremental search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, this option in XE5 is now named *Entire Scope*:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Find

Comment: I wonder what does the documentation mean by `Shift+F`, naturally it prints a capital 'f'.